Why do some people say tefilat haderech on flights?
Tefilat haderech is said after traveling a parsah outside of the city. (Shulchan Arukh, Orach Chayim 110:7)
Eliyahu hanavi is said to have flown on Shabbat more than tchum outside off city limits (Eruvin 43). From there, it says that flying doesn’t count as traveling (at least in matters of techum Shabbat).
Can we learn from here that flying is considered traveling for any purposes?
If so, why do some say tefilat haderech when flying?
If not so what is the distinction between traveling in terms of t’chum and travel in terms of tefilat haderech?

Reminds me of something attributed to R' Chaim Brisker -- the Gemara says the ashes of sacrifice meat aren't like the sacrifice, because panim chadashos ba'u lechan. So if we need panim chadashos at a Sheva Brachos, why not just burn some meat to ash? It must be that the same term means different things in different contexts ...

You rely on a wrong assumption because you start with SA and not the Gemmorah. Tfilas Haderech is said in dangerous places, to begin with. The rest is details. Some orthodox rabbis don't consider intercity rides dangerous, so they say it without Sham and Malchus. Flight ARE considered dangerous, so the Tefilah is recited.

Remember: You’re flying in a giant multi-ton metal-winged torpedo with that stays in the air by basically swimming so fast that it doesn’t have time to fall, and stays stable by floating on high air pressure. It’s dangerous. That’s why we say it.

@Qwertrl wait till you hear where the earth is currently throttling through

@DoubleAA Heh. True, but the Earth isn’t going to fall, nor will its atmosphere completely split open.  It also won’t experience dangerously-severe turbulence, or be hijacked by alien terrorists.

@Qwerty the world is currently falling into a huge nuclear explosion, but it's just moving so fast it overshoots. Plus there already was a hole in the atmosphere, and I don't know what an alien civilization is capable of. Ever felt the turbulence when the island you're currently floating on in a sea of molten lava shifts suddenly?

@DoubleAA Earthquakes! Forgot about those. But we do say Gomel after a life-threatening earthquake. And the force of gravity isn’t likely to randomly strengthen in the future, thereby pulling us into the sun. And although the ozone hole does let in radiation, it’s not immediately life-threatening. I was referring to a theoretical hole in every layer of the atmosphere, where breathing would be impossible, among other major issues.

Note, that the rules of techum Shabbos go to a distance of 1 mil = 2000 amah (Section 3, Chapter IV/C p. 1389 vol. IV of the 39 melachos). The rules of tefilas haderekh begin applicable only after traveling 1 parsa = 8000 amah. These are different domains and one should expect different halachic rulings with respect to traveling in each one of them.
Flying out of reshus harabim above 10 tefachim puts a person into makom petur, which allows carrying and travelling. It is free from all restrictions of melacha of hotzoa including techum Shabbos (Section 3, Chapter I/D on p. 1322, vol. IV of the "39 melachos" by R. Dovid Ribiat). One is also permitted to move from any other domain of Shabbos, such as reshus hayachid or karmelis into makom petur.
On the other hand, if one goes out of the city into makom petur with respect to shabbos and extends the travel to 1 parsa, say in the middle of a forest, a desert, or sea, one still has to say tefilas haderekh.
Alternatively, restrictions on travel on Shabbos are guarding one's ability to rest. The flight under such circumstances is not a common matter. Tefilas haderekh is a personal safety request, which is always important to have on long journeys.

I don't see any mention of techum in that section of 39 Melochos.

@shmosel My edition is from 2003. The techumim are set later i the book on the ground. Makom p'tur is defined as a place free of any restrictions of shabbos. I added reference or techum.
